# How to mock lambda parameter in mockito-kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I've got an interface:

```
interface DistanceChecker {
   fun checkDistance(locationData: LocationData, result: (Boolean) -> Unit)
}
```

I need to mock this method, but I don't call it explicitly, it's injected into logic.
This construction does not work:

```
    doAnswer {
        it.getArgument<(Boolean) -> Unit>(1).invoke(true)

        null
    }.`when`(distanceChecker).checkDistance(
        same(
            LocationData(
                LatLng(.0, .0),
                LatLng(.0, .0),
                .0
            )
        ),
        any()
    )
```

By this I got a stubbing error:

```
- this invocation of 'checkDistance' method:
distanceChecker.checkDistance(
LocationData(point=0.0_0.0, location=0.0_0.0, zoneRadius=0.0),
(kotlin.Boolean) -> kotlin.Unit
);
- has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
1. distanceChecker.checkDistance(
LocationData(point=0.0_0.0, location=0.0_0.0, zoneRadius=0.0),
null
);
```

Is there any way to mock lambda like that?

Comment: Why not just pass in a _real_ lambda that has the behavior you desire?

Comment: @LouisWasserman the content of lambda is what I want to test, but I need to pass parameter to lambda, in the sample it is **true**

Comment: That's not really reflected in your code, where you are *specifying* the behavior of the lambda in the test, which is pretty useless if you're testing it.